# Unable to use BsonIgnoreIfDefault for property of type long

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

```
[BsonDefaultValue(0)]
[BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
public long TotalItems { get; set; }
```

The attribute **[BsonDefaultValue(0)]** is preventing the complete document being inserted into the mongo whereas I just want to prevent storing TotalItems if its value is zero.
If I don't use the attributes [BsonDefaultValue(0)], [BsonIgnoreIfDefault] the the document is inserted properly in the db with TotalItems is inserted in the document as **"TotalItems" : NumberLong(0)"** which I actually don't want to strore into db if its zero. My question why [BsonDefaultValue(0)], [BsonIgnoreIfDefault] attributes preventing the insertion of the complete document.

Note: I am able to use the above two attributes with properties of type int.

Answer (score 4):

Minor error there, you need to cast your default value to a long:

```
[BsonDefaultValue((long)0)]
[BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
public long TotalItems { get; set; }
```