# How do I update a document in MongoDB & change all properties apart from_id in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, bson

```
public class UserObject
{
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }// Self generated
    public ulong UserID { get; set; } // Self generated
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string CharClass{ get; set; }
    public int CharLevel { get; set; }
    public int CharColour { get; set; }
}
```

I want to update just the Username, CharClass, CharLevel & CharColour.

I currently have this:

```
var client = new MongoClient(DBString);
var database = client.GetDatabase("UserLists");
var collection = database.GetCollection<UserObject>(Convert.ToString(GuildId));

var filter = Builders<UserObject>.Filter.Eq(s => s.Username, newUserName);

var UpdatedUserObject = new UserObject
{
    UserID = UserId,
    Username = newUserName,
    CharClass = newCharClass,
    CharLevel = newCharLevel,
    CharColour = newCharColour 
};

collection.ReplaceOneAsync(filter, UpdatedUserObject);
```

If you have any suggestions that would be much appreciated, i've got the add working i just can't seem to get the update, thanks!

Comment: Use collection.UpdateOne()

Comment: I get the error: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'TrustMeBot.UserObject' to 'MongoDB.Driver.UpdateDefinition<TrustMeBot.UserObject>' TrustMeBot

When i change it to UpdateOne()

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing:

```
var client = new MongoClient(DBString);
var database = client.GetDatabase("UserLists");
var collection = database.GetCollection<UserObject>(Convert.ToString(GuildId));

var filter = Builders<UserObject>.Filter.Eq(s => s.Username, newUserName);

var UpdatedUserObject = new UserObject
{
    UserID = UserId,
    Username = newUserName,
    CharClass = newCharClass,
    CharLevel = newCharLevel,
    CharColour = newCharColour 
};

collection.ReplaceOne(filter, UpdatedUserObject);
```

Which then gave me the problem that it was trying to update the _id so i used this stack overflow to put [BsonIgnoreIfDefault] on it so it didn't try and update:

[Unable to use BsonIgnoreIfDefault for property of type long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601732/unable-to-use-bsonignoreifdefault-for-property-of-type-long)

```
public class UserObject
{
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }// Self generated
    public ulong UserID { get; set; } // Self generated
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string CharClass{ get; set; }
    public int CharLevel { get; set; }
    public int CharColour { get; set; }
}
```

After this was fixed i found that the problem was that I was passing through the wrong username so it never matched & therefore didn't find anything to update, just me being stupid really, Thanks for the help